# android bluetooth low energy status = 61

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

> 07-02 10:12:19.416: D/BluetoothGatt(31605): onClientConnectionState()
>   - status=61 clientIf=5 device=78:A5:04:07:D1:3D

What is status 61 of Bluetooth LE in Android?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As per spec, error 61 (0x3d) means "CONNECTION TERMINATED DUE TO MIC FAILURE". The Message Integrity Check (MIC) is a 4-bytes extra field added to the BLE packet when encryption is enabled. That means the MIC failed on a packet received on your phone, which causes disconnection.

Comment: do you mean 0x3d?